# How to replace first byte in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdata

I have a file with hex byte. I use NSData to read this file,then convert NSdata to int. Now  I want to replace first byte in file to other value. Example: first byte when convert to int is 49, i want to change it to 48 and then replace it on file. How can i do that? This is my code:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"file"];
    NSLog(@"Patch File: %@",data);
    NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithData:[data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)]];
    int value = *(int*)([theData bytes]);
     NSLog(@"%d",value);
    if( value == 49)
        value = 48;
     NSLog(@"%d",value);
```

When run above code, it show :

```
<31414142 42434344 44454546 4654502d 4c494e4b 2d544553 54000000 00000000 00000000>
```

I want replace first byte to 0x02. how can i do that? Thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no need to use `replaceBytesInRange:` if you are only replacing one byte.

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"test"];

char *bytes = [data mutableBytes];
if (bytes[0] == 49)
    bytes[0] = 48;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![data writeToFile:@"file" options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error])
    NSLog(@"Error occurred: %@", error);
```

If you are trying to read the binary representation of an `int` from a file, you will need to use:

```
int value;
[data getBytes:&value length:sizeof value];

if (value == 1234)
    value = 4321;

[data replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, sizeof value) withBytes:&value];
```

Comment: I have any question: if it need change to 0x02, is it 2 of int type?

Comment: Yes, 0x02 is an integer. If you use `'2'` instead of `0x02` then it will be the *character* 2.

Comment: @user2656381: That will work. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve so I can't say whether or not it will do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

"`NSMutableData`" has a very handy function ["`replaceBytesInRange: withBytes:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableData/replaceBytesInRange%3awithBytes%3a) that you can use to replace things.

So modify your code to look something like this:

```
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"test"];
    NSLog(@"Patch File: %@",data);
    int value;

    [data getBytes: &value range: NSMakeRange(0,1)];
    NSLog(@"%d",value);

    if( value == 49)
        value = 48;

    [data replaceBytesInRange: NSMakeRange(0,1) withBytes: &value];

    NSLog(@"%d",value);

    NSError * error = nil;
    BOOL success = [data writeToFile: @"file" options: NSDataWritingAtomic error: &error];
    if(success == NO)
    {
        NSLog( @"error writing data out -- %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Comment: I want set first byte is 0x02. how can i do that? Thanks much

Comment: I used your code, it error:[NSConcreteData replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10056ad80
2013-08-07 11:22:23.374 test[1464:303] -[NSConcreteData replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10056ad80

Comment: +1, although strictly speaking it's a *method*, not a function. I posted an alternative answer as well.

Comment: @user2656381: You are not using an `NSMutableData` object, you using an `NSData` object. `replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:` is only valid for mutable data objects.

Comment: the reason you're seeing the error is because you're trying to replace bytes in an immutable NSData object.  It needs to be ***NSMutableData***.